# parse function is deprecated in url Module when i Parse a Url module

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, module

when I coding a server application in node js, I need to parse a URL . so I imported the URL  module and used the parse function. but it doesn't work. it shows parse was deprecated. how to fix it? answers, please...

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLJRB.png)

```js
 var http=require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
var url=require('url')

http.createServer(function (req,res){
    var q=url.parse(req.url)
    console.log(q.pathname)

    if(req.url==='/'){
fs.readFile('sample.html',function (err,data){
   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'})
    res.write(data)
    res.end()
})

}else if(req.url==='/signup'){
    fs.readFile('signup.html',(err,data)=>{
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'})
        res.write(data)
        res.end() 
    })
   
    
}
else if (req.url==='/signupaction'){
    res.write('sucessfully signup')
    res.end()
}

else{
    res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/html'})
    res.write('error')
    res.end()
}

}).listen(7000,()=>
    console.log("server started now")
)
```

Comment: It doesn't say it's deprecated, it says it's undefined.

Comment: You don't seem to be running the same code that's displayed. The error message says `var q = urlparse(url)`, but the code shown is `var q = url.parse(req.url)`.

Comment: how i can fix it?